# Remove duplicates from select using AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drupal

I'm building an events app that uses JSON from Drupal to display events in AngularJS (within a Drupal module). One of the JSON object keys is 'genre' and I'm using this on a select dropdown so the user can filter the events by genre.

I've tried the ng-option and ng-repeat methods to populate the select, and I found that only the ng-repeat worked, but of course it adds an option for each instance of an event with a particular genre - so if I have two music events I get two music options in the select. So now I'm trying to remove the duplicates.

I've tried ui.unique but that removed all but one of the options, not the duplicates. I've also tried a custom filter and had a similar problem. I think the structure of either the data or the AngularJS app is weird so it might be better to try a directive but I'm lost without JQuery and need help! I'm open to any suggestions.

JSON

```
{"nodes":[
   {"node":{
       "title":"The Awesome Band",
       "date":"2015-03-14T00:00:00+00:00",
       "venue":"The Place",
       "image":{
           "src":"/images/band.jpg",
           "alt":"The Awesome Band at The Place"
            },
        "time":"8pm",
        "taxonomy":"Rock",
        "genre":"Music Event"
        }
     }]}
```

JS

```
var weekEvents = angular.module('weekEvents',[]);
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('weekEvents-app'), ['weekEvents']);
    });

var weekEventsController = function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('/json/next7days').success(function(result){
        $scope.weekEvents = (function(){
            return result.nodes;
        })();
    });
};

weekEvents.directive('genreSelect', function(){
  return{
       restrict: "AE",
       link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
          elem.slice.call(elem.options)
          .map(function(a){
                if(this[a.value]){ 
                    elem.removeChild(a); 
                } else { 
                    this[a.value]=1; 
                } 
        },{});
    }
}
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="weekEvents-app">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8"  ng-controller="weekEventsController">

        <h2>This week</h2>
        <select ng-model="showGenre" name="genreSelect" data-genre-select>
                <option value="All" selected>All</option>
                <option ng-repeat="event in weekEvents" value="{{event.node.genre}}">{{event.node.genre}}</option>
        </select>

        <div class="mainEventItem" ng-repeat="event in weekEvents | orderBy:sortOrder | filter:showGenre">  
            <main-item-container>
                <div class="mainItem" ng-click="expandItem()">
                    <img src="{{event.node.image.src}}" alt="{{event.node.image.alt}}" class="img-responsive mainItemImg"/>
                    <div class="mainItemDetails">
                    <h2 class="eventTitle">{{event.node.title}}</h2>
                    <p class="eventDate">{{event.node.date | date: 'EEEE'}} / {{event.node.field_time}} / {{event.node.venue}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="animate-show mainItemDesc lightLink" ng-show='!collapsed'>
                    <p><strong>{{event.node.venue}} | {{event.node.cost}}</strong></p>
                    <p>{{event.node.description}}</p>
                    <a ng-href="{{event.node.Path}}">MORE</a>
                </div>
            </main-item-container>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of doing it, probably not the most efficient, especially for big array, but you get the idea:

```
$scope.getWeekEventsGenres = function() {
    return $scope.weekEvents.map(function (event) {
      return event.node.genre;
    })
    //maybe sort?
    .sort()
    //remove duplicates
    .filter(function(item, pos) {
      return a.indexOf(item) == pos;
    });
}

<option ng-repeat="event in getWeekEventsGenres()" ...>...</option>
```

Comment: If you want more efficient, just do that whenever weekEvents is updated, store the result in another variable, and use that variable in your ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I never managed to get this to work so I've given up on Angular with Drupal for now!